# What is Alternate of Providing View-model for Join Query in mvc5

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am Passing Different Model in a single View by Using a View model 'UserinfoVieModel'
The Syntax of my controller is

```
 select new UserInfoViewModel
             {
               UserInfoID = user.UserInfoID,
               AvatarURL = user.AvatarURL,
               UserFullName = user.UserFullName,
               ThreadSnippet = c.ThreadSnippet,
               MessageStarterUserId = c.MessageStarterUserId,
               MultipleReceiversId = c.MultipleReceiversId,
               LastMessageTime = c.LastMessageTime
              }
```

What My area of Concern is that when i am passing This model i am getting all blank data from all the classes which i have described in UserinfoVieModel

```
public class UserInfoViewModel
    {
        public virtual string Id { get; set; }
        public Guid UserInfoID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; } 
        public String DbType { get; set; }
        public Guid UserLevelEnumId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }//male/female/unknown
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public int Zipcode { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public int CountFollowers { get; set; }
        public int CountFollows { get; set; }
        public int CountFiles { get; set; }
        public int CountPhotos { get; set; }

\\ and many other Attributes
}
```

So Please tell me some method so that My linq query Performance increases by receiving specific data which  i want .

This is my Action Method

```
 var searchMessageThread = from c in db.MessageThreads 
                                      where c.MessageStarterUserId == loginUserId && c.isGroup == false
                                      join user in db.UserInfos
                                      on c.MultipleReceiversId equals user.UserInfoID
                                      select new UserInfoViewModel
                                      {
                                          UserInfoID = user.UserInfoID,
                                          AvatarURL = user.AvatarURL,
                                          UserFullName = user.UserFullName,
                                          ThreadSnippet = c.ThreadSnippet,
                                          MessageStarterUserId = c.MessageStarterUserId,
                                          MultipleReceiversId = c.MultipleReceiversId,
                                          LastMessageTime = c.LastMessageTime
                                      }
                                      ;
            return PartialView("_GetThread", searchMessageThread.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastMessageTime).ToList());
```

Comment: please show me your action method ?

Comment: What do you expect? You only assign seven of many values in the `select new UserInfoViewModel` statement. How would the other properties *not* be blank?

Answer (score 1):

If you does not want to bind view_model then change your Action Method like these

```
var searchMessageThread = from c in db.MessageThreads 
                                  where c.MessageStarterUserId == loginUserId && c.isGroup == false
                                  join user in db.UserInfos
                                  on c.MultipleReceiversId equals user.UserInfoID
                                  select new 
                                  {
                                      UserInfoID = user.UserInfoID,
                                      AvatarURL = user.AvatarURL,
                                      UserFullName = user.UserFullName,
                                      ThreadSnippet = c.ThreadSnippet,
                                      MessageStarterUserId = c.MessageStarterUserId,
                                      MultipleReceiversId = c.MultipleReceiversId,
                                      LastMessageTime = c.LastMessageTime
                                  }
                                  ;
        return PartialView("_GetThread", searchMessageThread.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastMessageTime).ToList());
```

**check select new**